# UNIX AIX PROMPT - Display files in color

Tags: unix, aix, prompt

I would like to show in my unix aix prompt all the files in a bright green color.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that your question is off-topic here on StackOverflow. See [faq#questions]. You might want to try [su] instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on AIX and ls --color does not work, you can try installing coreutils from IBM's site...

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/

It will update ls to include color.  Note, if you do not have su rights, you could also just place a copy of the coreutils ls file in your home/bin directory. And modify your PATH variable to check home/bin before /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the man page for `ls` and its `--color` option.  It may do what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't exist in my UNIX AIX version...
I was looking for another way of doing it...